# Generating range/interval from a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list and a tuple like below,

```
l = [3,5,7,8]
t = (5,15)
```

I want to check whether each element of the list falls in the range specified by the tuple. So, here 7,8 is the answer. I came up with the following one, but I am sure there is a better way.

```
for ele in l:
    if ele > t[0] and ele < t[1]:
        print "Founde it", ele
```

Is there a way to convert it into range/interval and check directly? Or any one liner ?

Comment: A one-liner for what? Your comparison is already one line.

Comment: `if x in xrange(a,b)` amounts to `if a <= x < b`.

Comment: `[num for num in l if t[0] < num < t[1]]`?

Comment: Implementation note: in 2.7, `ele in range(a,b)` executes in O(b-a) time, whereas `ele >= a and ele < b` runs in O(1) time. So for all but the closest-together values of `a` and `b`, consider using the inequality anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as follows:

```
print [ele for ele in l if ele > t[0] and ele <t[1]]
```

This outputs `7` and `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension might be better, or `filter` and `lambda`.

```
[num for num in l if t[0] < num < t[1]]
```

or

```
filter(lambda n: t[0] < n < t[1], l)
```